# Error performing MessageBroadcastJob from Async(default) : ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, actioncable

I am trying to learn ActionCable by making a private 1-on-1 chat app with Rails 6 and ActionCable. After Message create commit, I am performing a messageBroadcast Job as can be seen in my Message.rb model file:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

  after_create_commit { MessageBroadcastJob.perform_later(self) }
end
```

My message broadcast job also looks fine to me. It however generating a wrong number of arguments, which makes no sense to me. Below is my message_braodcast_job.rb file:

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    sender = message.user
    recipient = message.conversation.opposed_user(sender)
    broadcast_to_sender(sender, message)
    broadcast_to_recipient(recipient, message)
  end

  private

  def broadcast_to_sender(user, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{user.id}",
      message: render_message(message, user),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def broadcast_to_recipient(user, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{user.id}",
      window: render_window(message.conversation, user),
      message: render_message(message, user),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def render_message(message, user)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'messages/message',
      locals: { message: message, user: user }
     )
  end

  def render_window(conversation, user)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'conversations/conversation',
      locals: { conversation: conversation, user: user }
    )
  end
end
```

I have no clue why this error occurs. A look at the trace was not especially helpful for me:

```
    ConversationChannel#speak({"message"=>[{"name"=>"conversation_id", "value"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"user_id", "value"=>"4"}, {"name"=>"body", "value"=>"hgyhhhh"}]})
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:16:in `speak'
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:16:in `speak'
  Conversation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:16:in `speak'
  Message Create (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "user_id", "conversation_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "hgyhhhh"], ["user_id", 4], ["conversation_id", 2], ["created_at", "2021-05-10 10:47:32.689339"], ["updated_at", "2021-05-10 10:47:32.689339"]]
  ↳ app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:16:in `speak'
  TRANSACTION (5.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:16:in `speak'
[ActiveJob] Enqueued MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000000000b21f768 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://group12/Message/19>>
  Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec] Performing MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec) from Async(default) enqueued at 2021-05-10T10:47:32Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000000000b2b3df0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://group12/Message/19>>
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   ↳ app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb:5:in `perform'
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   Conversation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   ↳ app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb:6:in `perform'
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   ↳ app/models/conversation.rb:22:in `opposed_user'
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   ↳ app/models/conversation.rb:22:in `opposed_user'
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec]   Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 28)
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec] Error performing MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: f5861f88-fa39-4976-a7ca-65b4009610ec) from Async(default) in 54.26ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)):
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actioncable-6.1.3.1/lib/action_cable/server/broadcasting.rb:24:in `broadcast'
C:/Users/Moussa Sarr/OneDrive/Desktop/Group12/app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb:14:in `broadcast_to_sender'
C:/Users/Moussa Sarr/OneDrive/Desktop/Group12/app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb:7:in `perform'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:48:in `block in perform_now'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/i18n-1.8.10/lib/i18n.rb:314:in `with_locale'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/timezones.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Timezones>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:21:in `block in instrument'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:31:in `instrument'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Instrumentation>'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activejob-6.1.3.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block in tag_logger'
```